# Gson: Expected a STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT -- how do I handle this scenario?

Tags: java, json, gson

My JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "cid": "9779849461208",
        "accountNumber": "00105140001799",
        "cardNumber": "1111111111111111",
        "nickName": "kirantest",
        "defaultAccount": true,
        "verified": true,
        "bank": "004",
        "verifiedDate": {
            "date": {
                "year": 2017.0,
                "month": 5.0,
                "day": 17.0
            },
            "time": {
                "hour": 10.0,
                "minute": 59.0,
                "second": 28.0,
                "nano": 8.14E8
            }
        },
        "active": false,
        "code": "ddc84fcb5e164cb8b8fd2ca971b5e6ee"
    }
]
```

My code to convert JSON to a `List`:

```java
String json = JsonUtils.toString((List<UserAccount>) response.getData());
List<UserAccount> list = JsonUtils.toObjectList(json, new TypeToken<List<UserAccount>>() {}.getType());
```

utility method GSON

```
 public static <T> T toObjectList(String data, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(data, type);
 }
```

Comment: please paste the logcat and UserAccount class code.

Comment: Let's do some magic here: `verifiedDate` is supposed to come as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified date is supposed to come as a String as mentioned by @Lyubomyr Shaydariv